# Finding inverting vs non inverting functions

Tags: digital-logic, cmos, nmos, pmos

I'm learning CMOS systems and I'm struggling with the PMOS and NMOS part of it. So for example given `F=minterms(m0,m1,m2...)` I can do the kmap and get the function no problem but how do I know if what I have is the PMOS or NMOS function? I know PMOS is inverted and NMOS is non-inverted (if I understand correctly) so I guess my questions are:

- How do I know if I have a inverting/non-inverting function?
- And once I know which one I have (lets say I have PMOS), to get the NMOS do I find the complemented version of the PMOS function?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please define what you specifically mean by functions (minterms(m0,m1...) and kmap. These are not general cmos terms.

Comment: @pat given a function of minterm values we create a kmap to come up with a logic function in the form of AB+DB' , then using this function a cmos circuit is made. A more specific example is f=(AB)! , the explanation says that this is an inverting expression and they later use demorgans theorem to get f=A!+B! and call this a non-inverting expression. Given the explanation below however I think I am doing this wrong and its the signals themselves which determine nmos or pmos

Comment: Ah ok, karnaugh map. Makes more sense. Maybe you could show a more specific example of how these functions are to be implemented in CMOS. The answer explains some possibilities.  You can usually realize any of these functions using and, or, and not gates. The gates can be comprised of complementary nmos and pmos devices.

Comment: @pat oh haha my apologies yes karnaugh maps. An exact question is: Derive a CMOS circuit for the logic function F(x1,x2,x3,x4)=(sumof)m(0,1,2,4,5,6,8,9,10) hint: simplify all variables as complement (pull-up network)

Comment: So, when he says simplify the variables as a complement (pun). Take F(0,1,0,0) =m(4). If you use the pull up network in a CMOS NAND gate then PMOS devices a,c, & d will pull up the output to VDD or high. Since you are summing all the outputs only that high output and those output that go high (in your function truth table) will get or'd together to produce a final one. The pull down network will automatically follow as it will be open as in that example case.

Answer (score 2):

Gates are composed of two sets of switches: the ‘pull-up’ network and ‘pull-down’ network. Each network has FETs in series, parallel, or some combination of the two.

In general, p-FETs are used on the pull-up side while n-FETs are used on the pull-down. This gives the best possible gate-source voltage arrangement to drive each FET type into its saturation region:

- p-FET: gate threshold is negative vs. source, source is connected to VDD
- n-FET: gate threshold is positive vs. source, source is connected to VSS

Inherently then, both p-FETs and n-FETs invert. The very simplest CMOS gate, the inverter, uses a p-n pair: one p-FET for the pull-up network, one n-FET for the pull down:

- Logic high in n-FET is on, output is low
- Logic low in, p-FET is on, output is high.

Note: this gate-source voltage relationship applies for *enhancement mode* FETs, the type used in CMOS logic. *Depletion mode* FETs will have different thresholds, and see use as pull-up resistor elements for NMOS and certain simplified elements like RAM cells.

Comment: So it is the signals themselves which determine whether I am using a pmos or nmos transistors and then using those transistors I create the logic expressions in the functions? Also thank you so much for the answer

Comment: Yes, pretty much. The transistors have to be biased the right way to work as switches.